# Пустая колонка в ListView

Tags: android

Есть таблица Parse.com с 20-ю значениями, ListView скачивает каждое значение (независимо от того, есть там содержимое или нет). Получается, что когда в парсе существует всего 2-3 текста, то listView скачивает эти 2-3 текста и оставляет остальные 18 строчек пустыми. Какое условие создать, чтобы пустые строчки не скачивались? P/S/ удалять строчки из Парса нельзя.

Код:

```
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SevenActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("LikedFar");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "LikedFar");
        // query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SevenActivity.this,
                R.layout.listview_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("LikedFar"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        setLV();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, и заполнение адаптера данными происходит в этом коде

```
for (ParseObject country : ob) {
    adapter.add((String) country.get("LikedFar"));
}
```

то почему бы не поставить проверку на пустое значение, типа такой:

```
for (ParseObject country : ob) {
    String line = (String) country.get("LikedFar");
    if(!line.isEmpty()) {
        adapter.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: теперь несколько строк  последний (2) обрезаются и становятся невидимы, хотя содержимое есть. В чем может быть проблема? (Это не мой комментарий, комментарий содержится в правке от анонимного пользователя, потенциального автора вопроса)